# html code in email body in java class

Tags: java, html, email

I want to send email to customer with shop name, shop address, shop contact number where shop contact contact number should be used like

```
<a href='tel:"+shopInfoForEmail.getContactNo()+"'>"+shopInfoForEmail.getContactNo()+"</a>"
```

but i could not set this info with html code. My email code is

```
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(barberConstants.systemEmail));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(userEmail));
        message.setSubject("ご予約ありがとうございます。");
        message.setText(userName+" 様," +
                "\n\n この度は "+shopName+" をご利用くださり誠にありがとうございます。 "+booking+" にてご予約を受付いたしました。 \n\n"
                +"店舗にてご予約を確認でき次第、改めて予約完了メールをお送りいたします。\n恐れ入りますが、いましばらくお待ちくださいますようお願いいたします。\n\n"+
                "※まだご予約は確定しておりません。\n※こちらは自動配信メールのため、ご返信はできかねます。予めご了承ください。\n\n"+
                "■店舗情報------------------------\n"+shopName+"\n"+**shopInfoForEmail.getContactNo()**+
                "\n"+shopAddress+"\n"+shopInfoForEmail.getUrl()+"\n--------------------------------------");            
        Transport.send(message);
```

want to set href:tel in **shopInfoForEmail.getContactNo()**. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly your problem is? Do you get an error, don't you know how to do it (what exactly?) in general? Don't you get the expected output?

Comment: i tried to change message.setText to message.setContent("...", text/html) then japanese character not shown and also not working href:tel ... thats why i want to know how to do pls

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use Velocity Template to send HTML content.

[see here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html)

Comment: sorry i dont know about this

Answer (score 0):

In order to use href:tel you should encode the url-telephone number.

You can use

```
String telephoneUrl=URLEncoder.encode("tel:"+shopInfoForEmail.getContactNo(), "UTF-8");
```

then use your encoded url to create html.

Comment: no working. if i click to phone number it goes to yahoo bounce page

Comment: now I understood your problem see updated answer above

Comment: but how to put <a href=telephoneUrl></a> in message.setText() ?